# Detatching threads and ARC under iOS 5: how to make compatible code with 4.3?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting

So, I got a place in my code where I detach a thread and it runs fine.

Until I run the code on iOS 4.3, then it goes bananas with billions of "Object 0x1045660 of class `NSCFString` autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking" errors.

But I cant place an autorelease pool inside the method called by the thread, because `NSAutoReleasePool` cant be used when ARC is on.

So, what do?

Comment: Isn't there an @autorelease directive or something? Just a wild stab here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bracket it in @autoreleasepool { }

Comment: For me aslo the same error is getting. As you said I put my code inside as @autoreleasepool {
     
         while(1) {
             [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(updateCountdown) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
             [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];
         }
     }

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't you just surround your code with
    @autorelease {
        // your code here
    }
?